# How can I get these java line algorithms working?

Tags: java, algorithm, line, draw

I'm trying to demonstrate Bresenham's line algorithm as opposed to a less sophisticated approach. I'm very new to programming and I'm sure my problems are elementary, but a solution and an explanation would be hugely helpful. Thanks!

This first block of code comes straight out of my book.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class lines extends JPanel {
    int deltaX;
    int deltaY;
    int DY2;
    int DX2;
    int Di;

    public void basic(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Graphics
    g){
        int deltaX = x2-x1;
        int deltaY = y2-y1;
        float m = (float)deltaY/(float)deltaX;
        float c = y1 - (m*x1);
        for (int x=x1; x<x2; x++){
            float floatY = (m*x) + c;
            int y = Math.round(floatY);
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y);
        }
    }

   public void brz(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2,
    Graphics g){
    deltaX = x2-x1;
    deltaY = y2-y1;
    DY2 = 2* deltaY;
    DX2 = 2* deltaX;
    Di = DY2 - deltaX;
    int x = x1;
    int y = y1;
    int prevy;
    while (x<x2) {
        x++;
        prevy = y;
        if (Di > 0){
            y++;
        }
        g.drawLine(x,y,x,y);
        Di = Di + DY2 - (DX2 * (y - prevy));
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    basic(10,10,40,30,g);
    basic(10,10,40,90,g);
    brz(50,50,150,60,g);
    brz(50,50,150,120,g);
    brz(50,50,150,140,g);
}
```

It told me I need a main class, so I added this bit:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     paintComponent(Graphics g);
}
```

Now it's giving me this:

`lines.java:15: ')' expected
paintComponent(Graphics g);`

`lines.java:15: illegal start of expression
paintComponent(Graphics g);`

Comment: If you formatted your code, you would see better.

Comment: We're not a syntax-checking service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside main change the line to

```
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint ");

    f.add(new YourPanelName());
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
```

then do some j2ee swings api study :)

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the type when passing it into a method. Change `paintComponent(Graphics g);` to `paintComponent(g);` on what appears to be line 15. You only declare a type when *accepting* arguments or declaring fields/variables.

Comment: @ajb I am not psychic, and I do not know the OP's intentions. Writing the code for the OP wouldn't really be the way to go here.

Comment: Since this seems to be a lesson in coding a line-drawing algorithm rather than a class in how to use Swing, I think helping OP get started with the magic incantations you need to use Swing is appropriate in this case.

Comment: @ajb Sadly, I have never used Swing except with existing code to be edited, and I will fall short here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct the object before putting it into the method.

`paintComponent(Graphics g);` - **NO**
`paintComponent(g);` - **YES**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Graphics g = new Graphics(); 
    paintComponent(g);
}
```

[Read more about the graphics class here!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)

Comment: `Graphics g = new Graphics();` Won't compile. It's an abstract class, you will have to write down code for all its methods

Comment: plus `paintComponent(g)` won't compile, because it's an instance method and you're calling it from the static `main` method without having an instance to apply it to.

Comment: @ajb Exactly, it should be static in order to be called